# X11 sessions: when a session starts and ends, does `gdm` run a session?

Tags: x11, xorg

I'm quite confused with X11 sessions. Namely, I don't understand, when an X session starts:

- I want to programmatically start an X session with my own `bob-session` program, analogous to `gnome-session`. How do I do that? Or what do `gnome-session` or `gdm` do to start a new session?
- When we run X upon boot, do they run any session?
- When gdm/xdm etc. run, do they run under certain X session or not? Programs, started by gdm config (e.g. virtual keyboard) don't run under any X session?
- What happens to a user session, when we switch a user at hotseat in Gnome?
- Does XDMCP protocol mean that Xserver might run on machine A (terminal) and gdm run on machine B and user can login to B from A?

Could you provide some instructive cases of events, happening to X session?